# setting proxy in docker-compose v2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have proxy setting for docker containers in $HOME/.docker/config.json

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
    "default":
    {
         "httpProxy": "http://adress",
         "httpsProxy": "http://adress",
         "noProxy": ",10.225.226.0/24"
       }
  }
}
```

it works just fine with"old", written in python, docker-compose. but this new v2, written in go, seems to ignore this file. i.e.
`docker-compose build` is working, but new `docker compose build` gives me error from yum (from inside the container) that it cannot connect to network. tried to google it, but everything is still about old version of docker-compose, or about docker-compose file format. am i missing something? is there a new config file, or some options to turn on? i know i can set ENV HTTPS_PROXY in Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml, but i don't want to make them dependent on building environment

Answer (score 0):

The [fix for this](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/pull/2053) was merged in a month ago, so you should see it working correctly with an upgrade to 2.0.0 or newer.

Comment: i have 2.0.1, does not work for me
```⋊> ~ docker compose version                                                                                                                                                                                14:02:38
Docker Compose version v2.0.1
⋊> ~  ```

Comment: @pawełbogaczewicz I'd recommend putting together a [mcve] and open an issue on https://github.com/docker/compose

Comment: i will. out of curiosity, dows it work to you? Dockerfile

Comment: Still does not work, cf. open ticket: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9034